# How to add console app in docker compose?

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, console

I have web app created in .net core and I added docker-compose with my app and SqlServer.
Then I created console app witch do migration my database.
But when I started my docker-compose in logs I see

> The specified framework can be found at:
>
> - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.10-x64
>
> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
> The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
>
> - No frameworks were found.
>
> You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

But I have .NET Core SDK 3.1.0, my web app use it.

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  productmanagment.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}productmanagmentapi
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ProductManagment.Api/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
      - migrator
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "MyPassword"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
  migrator:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}productmanagmentmigrator
    container_name: migrator
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ProductManagment.Migrator/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
        DbConnection: "Server=db;Database=ProductManagment;User=sa;Password=MyPassword"
```

And Dockerfile in Migrator(Console App)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProductManagment.Migrator/ProductManagment.Migrator.csproj", "ProductManagment.Migrator/"]
COPY ["ProductManagment.Api.csproj", "ProductManagment.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ProductManagment.Migrator/ProductManagment.Migrator.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ProductManagment.Migrator"
RUN dotnet build "ProductManagment.Migrator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProductManagment.Migrator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProductManagment.Migrator.dll"]
```

How to run properly this Console app and how to check its logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message you are getting, you should just need to change your base image from `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim` to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1` for the migrator application. Without seeing the code of your project, it's hard to say why you need to make this change.

This Microsoft document should also help to provide some insight: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows